# Complex number conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

I have $$\displaystyle E=\frac{(Z_1+Z_2)(Z_2+Z_3)...(Z_{n-1}+Z_n)(Z_n+Z_1)}{Z_1Z_2...Z_n}$$ and $|Z_k|=r \gt 0$ for any $k$  and $r$ is a real number.

I must prove $E=G$ where $G=\bar{E}$ , the conjugate of $E$. I've tried to write $E$ like that:
$$\displaystyle E=(1+Z_2/Z_1)(1+Z_3/Z_2)...(1+Z_n/Z_{n-1})(1+Z_1/Z_n)$$ and write trigonometry from of $Z_k$

$$Z_k=r(\cos X_k+i \sin X_k)$$ but from here I don't know.
and I tried by induction simply test $$P(1): \frac{(Z_1+Z_2)(Z_2+Z_1)}{Z_1Z_2}=2+\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}+\frac{Z_2}{Z_1},$$  if we write $Z_1=r(\cos X_1+i\sin X_1)$ and $Z_2=r(\cos X_2+i \sin X_2)$ and making a substitution in $P(1)$ we find $P(1)$ is true. but how to prove that if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true?

Can you help me?

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: $\;\displaystyle|Z_k|=r \iff \overline{Z_k}=\frac{r^2}{Z_k}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since $|z_k|=r>0$ for every $k=1,2,\dots,n$, we have:
$$|z_k|^2=r^2\Leftrightarrow z_k\overline{z_k}=r^2\Leftrightarrow\overline{z_k}=\frac{r^2}{z_k}$$.

So
$$\begin{align*}\overline{E}=&\overline{\left(\frac{(z_1+z_2)\dots(z_{n}+z_1)}{z_1z_2\dots z_n}\right)}=\frac{(\overline{z_1}+\overline{z_2})\dots(\overline{z_{n}}+\overline{z_1})}{\overline{z_1}\overline{z_2}\dots\overline{z_n}}=\frac{(\frac{r^2}{z_1}+\frac{r^2}{z_2})\dots(\frac{r^2}{z_{n}}+\frac{r^2}{z_1})}{\frac{r^2}{z_1}\frac{r^2}{z_2}\dots\frac{r^2}{z_n}}=\\
=&\frac{r^{2n}(\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_1z_2})\dots(\frac{z_{n}+z_1}{z_{1}z_n})}{r^{2n}\frac{1}{z_1z_2\dots z_n}}=\frac{(z_1+z_2)\dots(z_n+z_1)}{z_1z_2\dots z_n}=E
\end{align*}$$

And the requested has been proven.